# Java compiler: automatic downcasting generics?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, generics, intellij-idea

I have the following method signature

```
JavaPairRDD<K,Object>   countApproxDistinctByKey(double relativeSD)
```

from class

```
Class JavaPairRDD<K,V>
```

Javadoc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#countApproxDistinctByKey(double))

In my code, I do the following

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> mapToPair = ... some calculations ...
JavaPairRDD<String, Long> reachedDeviceRDD = mapToPair.countApproxDistinctByKey(0.01);
```

In Eclipse (Mars) this assignment throws the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from JavaPairRDD<String,Object> to JavaPairRDD<String,Long>
```

which is correct, given the above signature!

But my problem is that I have been programming for 6+ months with IntellijIdea, and this error has never shown up since now.
It doesn't even come up with NetBeans and it doesn't show up compiling the project in Maven (i.e. javac).

It seems to me that the compiler is "casting automatically" the Object generic parameter to Long, which would be madness.

I don't know what I'm missing.

Additional info:
The classes are from the Apache Spark project, which is written in Scala.

** Edit **
You can find a code example [here](https://github.com/besil/genericmadness):

Comment: "it doesn't show up compiling the project in Maven". Now that would be quite bizarre since Maven invokes javac. Can you post a reproducing code?

Comment: Yes, but eclipse uses jdt and not the javac that is present on the system. I have run into slight differences like this before.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You can find an example here:
https://github.com/besil/genericmadness

The problem seems related to the Tuple2 class (Scala) vs Tuple2<> (Java).
I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: The fact is that Eclipse JDT is correctly throwing the error, while javac ( and so maven, intellij, netbeans) does not. This behaviour changes adding or removing the diamond operator (<>) from Tuple2.
Without <>, types are not checked by the compiler!!

Comment: @besil of course not, raw types are not checked! Without <> you are not using generics.

Comment: Hi 1blustone. Sorry I don't understand: I'm using the <> operator, so I'm using the generics, am I not?
The problem is that I'm assigning a <String, Object> to <String, Long>.
What do you mean?